# Ensuring a unique socket.id over multiple app instances using socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am running a Node.js + Socket.io app over multiple instances with a Redis cache layer. I am wondering if the socket.id field for each connection would be unique over all instances. Is there a possibility that a socket.id on one instance can be the same as socket.id on another instance?

As far as I can see, the socket.id is generated using the following code:

```
/**
 * Interface to a `Client` for a given `Namespace`.
 *
 * @param {Namespace} nsp
 * @param {Client} client
 * @api public
 */

function Socket(nsp, client, query){
  this.nsp = nsp;
  this.server = nsp.server;
  this.adapter = this.nsp.adapter;
  this.id = nsp.name !== '/' ? nsp.name + '#' + client.id : client.id;
  this.client = client;
  this.conn = client.conn;
  this.rooms = {};
  this.acks = {};
  this.connected = true;
  this.disconnected = false;
  this.handshake = this.buildHandshake(query);
  this.fns = [];
}
```

I am unsure about what it is actually doing when creating the id field.

Comment: This sounds to me a lot like [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why Socket.id uniqueness is important at all? Could you describe what your actual problem is? It will increase chances to get useful answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you trace the flow further, you will realize the socket.io module depends on engine.io (https://github.com/socketio/engine.io). It uses the `id` generated by `engine.io`.

1.`engine.io` emits `connection` to socket.io server as per the code below:

```
Server.prototype.onconnection = function(conn){
  debug('incoming connection with id %s', conn.id);
  var client = new Client(this, conn);
```

`conn.id` has the unique id.

2.socket.io client code stores this id in its pointer

```
function Client(server, conn){
  this.server = server;
  this.conn = conn;
  this.encoder = new parser.Encoder();
  this.decoder = new parser.Decoder();
  this.id = conn.id;
```

3.Then when socket is created, same id is used

```
this.id = nsp.name !== '/' ? nsp.name + '#' + client.id : client.id;
```

Now back to the original question. The `id` is generated by engine.io using the following method:

```
/**
 * generate a socket id.
 * Overwrite this method to generate your custom socket id
 *
 * @param {Object} request object
 * @api public
 */

Server.prototype.generateId = function (req) {
  return base64id.generateId();
};
```

Here `base64id` and `generateId` are part of `npm` package `https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64id`. This package is supposed to generate a random base 64 id. I hope this helps you to understand that there is a very less probability of having the same id for 2 connections.  You do have an option to override this method if you don't prefer this algorithm

Answer (score 0):

The id will always be unique .this is due to fact that the id is based from the socket it was connected . Every socket is different.So every id is differet.
socket() 
| 
bind() 
| 
recvfrom() 
| 
(wait for a sendto request from some client) 
| 
(process the sendto request) 
| 
sendto (in reply to the request from the client...for example, send an HTML file)